# Atualizar dados MySQL com Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tenho uma tabela anúncios com um campo chamado destaque, por default seu valor é 0.

Eu listo todos os anúncios em uma table no HTML. Queria fazer com que quando o usuário clique em "Ativar destaque" o mesmo envie um update no MySQL alterando o campo de 0 para 1 sem refresh na página.

É possível?

Obs.: Antes que digam que eu não fui atras e quero pronto, eu fui sim, mas não consigo de forma alguma. Não estou pedindo código pronto, apenas um rumo.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione o código que você já fez.

Comment: Mostre seu código...

Answer (score 5):

Aqui tens uma ideia de como fazer segue o codigo abaixo

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document.body).on('click', '#id_botao', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = { 
            // Aqui passa as variaveis com os dados que serão de ser actualizados na base de dados
          };
        $(this).addClass("class"); // Aqui muda a class css caso queira
        $(this).text("texto"); // Aqui voce muda o texto do botao caso queira
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Fiheiro que faz update na bd",
            data: data,
            cache: true
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $("#sucesso").html("sucesso").fadeIn(400);
            $("#sucesso").fadeOut(4000); // Aqui apresenta uma mensagem de sucesso caso queira
        });
    });
});
```

Espero que ajude teste e só adaptar ao seu caso diga alguma coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Simples

JQuery/AJAX

```
$("#btn-destaque").click(function () { //Quando o botão destaque for pressionado
var idAnun = null; //Aqui você dá um jeito de passar a id do anuncio a receber o destaque
$.ajax({
    method: "post", //Escolhe o método de envio
    url: "/on-destaque.php", //O endereço do script php que fará o update
    data: {id: idAnun,action: 'on'} //Envio da ID do anuncio e a ação (ativar)

}).done(function (answer) {
    //ação em caso de sucesso

}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    //Ação em caso de falha
});
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once 'script_BD.php'; //Script com a conexão ao banco de dados
if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 0) { //$_POST['id'] != 0 (em caso de tabela auto incremento o id será do tipo inteiro e nunca será iniciada em 0) isso em MySQL não sei outros Bancos de dados
$db = connectdb(); //função do "script_BD.php"
$action = $_POST['action'] == 'on'? 1:0; //verifica o tipo de ação
$update = $db->prepare("UPDATE `tabela` SET `coluna_destaque` = :action WHERE id = :id");
$update->bindValue(":action",$action,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->bindValue(":id",$_POST['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->execute(); // executa update;
}
```

Bom digo a você que esse é um dos rumos para fazer esse update. Agora com esforço você conseguirá adaptá-lo a sua necessidade.

Usei PDO aqui não sei qual pratica você utiliza para se comunicar com o banco de dados.